# ASP.NET WebForms and MVC Hybrid - Strange characters in URL (random stuff)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of creating a hybrid webforms / mvc app. It all works find in VS with its debug web server. However, after overcoming numerous other issues and I am now stuck with a od problem indeed.

When viewing pages served by controllers I am getting random characters show up in the URL - but the site still works, I think.
For example, navigating to /Route/Index takes me to (S(1t2ba055d2unxyqllwuntf55))/Route/Index

Why are these odd characters being generated?

My routes look like this in Global.asax

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute("Route", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = "" });
```

I was informed I had to add a default route without a controller otherwise people could not navigate to / (the root). MVC would try and map this. Wonder if this controllerless rule is part of the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1t2ba055d2unxyqllwuntf55) looks like cookie-less sessions.  Check your web.config and make sure it reads something like:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" />
```

Comment: Not at all.  There's so many of these settings tucked in there it's easy to miss something like this.  Glad to see it resolved.